# Cannot place TextInputEditText on Top of TextInput Layout. AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

So I ran into a problem where I was trying to convert my EditText into TextInputEditText under TextInputLayout from com.google.material library.

I am not able to place my TextInputEdit Text On top of TextInputLayout
Here is a screeenshot.
[image: Click Here For Screenshot]

As you can see it is a bit off from both the top and left.

login.xml

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="  Email"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="101dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="366dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/signupemailfeild"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedittext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="  Password"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="101dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="444dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/signuppasswordfeild"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="match_parent" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

build.gradle(app:module)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
}
```

Update:- Fixed the X-axis Offset Now the problem is only with Y-axis Offset.
[Click Here For New Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB9si.png)

Comment: use at least the latest stable version: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

Comment: Use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in the `TextInputEditText` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the `TextInputLayout`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti it does kinda works but still has a little offset from top. Here is the screenshot [link](https://imgur.com/a/SPY1u1M)

Comment: Remove android:padding="5dp" in the TextInputLayout

Comment: tried @GabrieleMariotti Still the Y-axis offset remains. Content is completely visible but the offset still remains

Comment: Update the material components to 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply these changes:

- use the latest stable version of Material Components `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`
- use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the `TextInputLayout`
- remove `android:padding="5dp"`  in the `TextInputLayout`
- use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in the `TextInputEditText`
- remove `android:hint=" Password"` in the `TextInputEditText`
- change `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` to `app:endIconMode="password_toggle"`

Just use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="  Password"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        ...>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/signuppasswordfeild"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You So Much. Updating from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 worked. Have a nice day and  Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting android:layout_width and android:layout_height of TextInputEditText to "match_parent", You can also try to remove android:padding="5dp" from TextInputLayout if you want to fit it perfectly. Also remove android:hint="  Password" from second TextInputLayout. That's why you are getting double hints for the password.

Comment: @roshan_topno I did remove the Password and it did fixed the double hint, and Somehow i fixed the X-axis shift. The the only problem is with Y-axis shift.